# How to read an Excel file from a liferay portlet?

Tags: java, excel, client-server, liferay

I am developing an application based on Liferay, inside the "*processAction*" method I am calling a function from my class which is supposed to read an Excel file, but when I put this portlet on liferay it gives me errors such as:

"*org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception in java*"

Comment: you forgot to cross reference all the other places where you asked the same question. Please save us from doing duplicate work and link all identical posts, especially when they've already been answered

Answer (score 0):

Even i had got this problem and please provide full stacktrace.

In your Exception stacktrace check for

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at 
java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694)
```

this is because JVM doesnt have enough memory  try increasing JVM memory.

The other problem many be your using old xmlbeans.jar file try using the latest

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the stax API jar

If we look at the POI Components page we will see that the ooxml-schemas jar depends on a STAX API jar (most typically provided by stax-api-1.0.1.jar)

I Looked in my POI binary download, and in the ooxml-lib directory to see the jar I needed.